# check list value is in dictionary for python

Tags: python-2.7

how do I check if all value inside the list is in the dictionary?

```
'''

dict={
    "x": {
        "y": [
                {
                    "Id": "AB",
                    "Name": "C D E",
                    "cat": [
                        "cat"
                            ],
                    "stat": "NO",
                    "count1": 0,
                    "count2": 0,
                    "results": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": "CD",
                    "sourceName": "FGE",
                    "cat": [],
                    "stat": "NO",
                    "count1": 0,
                    "count2": 0,
                    "results": []
                }
            ]
        "z":[   {
                    "Id": "YC",
                    "Name": "C D E",
                    "cat": [
                        "cat"
                            ],
                    "stat": "NO",
                    "count1": 0,
                    "count2": 0,
                    "results": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": "PO",
                    "sourceName": "FGE",
                    "cat": [],
                    "stat": "NO",
                    "count1": 0,
                    "count2": 0,
                    "results": []
                }
            ]
        }      
    }
    
    list=['AB','CD']
    
    this is what I did but its not working
    
    def comp():
        leng=len(dict['x']['y'])
        for abc in leng:
            if dict['x']['y'][abc]['id'] == list[0]:
                print(list)
                list.pop(0)
                if list == []:
                    result='OK'
                    break
                else: result='Not OK!'
```

'''

I would like to make a function to compare that all value in list are exists in dict "y"['Id']

if all are exist then I want to get the result = ok otherwise result=not ok
appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dict have a missing comma, so it would throw an error:

```
dict={
    "x": {
        "y": [
                {
                    "Id": "AB",
                    "Name": "C D E",
                    "cat": [
                        "cat"
                            ],
                    "stat": "NO",
                    "count1": 0,
                    "count2": 0,
                    "results": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": "CD",
                    "sourceName": "FGE",
                    "cat": [],
                    "stat": "NO",
                    "count1": 0,
                    "count2": 0,
                    "results": []
                }
            ],
        "z":[   {
                    "Id": "YC",
                    "Name": "C D E",
                    "cat": [
                        "cat"
                            ],
                    "stat": "NO",
                    "count1": 0,
                    "count2": 0,
                    "results": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": "PO",
                    "sourceName": "FGE",
                    "cat": [],
                    "stat": "NO",
                    "count1": 0,
                    "count2": 0,
                    "results": []
                }
            ]
        }      
    }
```

You should get the key in the dict with the lists of value, so instead of:

```
for abc in dict
```

It should be:

```
for abc in dict['x']['y]
```

To check if the dict_value is in the list, you should do this:

```
if abc['Id'] in lst:
   lst.remove(abc['Id'])
```

Overall, it should look like this:

```
def comp():
    for abc in dict['x']['y']:
        if abc['Id'] in lst:
            lst.remove(abc['Id'])
    if not lst:
        return "ok"
    return "not ok"
```